# Animate Table Rows in Table Updated via HTMX

Tags: css, css-animations, htmx

I have a table that is updated via polling with HTMX, where each table row has a unique id. When a new row is deleted into the table or and existing row is updated, I want to animate this via CSS: deleted rows should fade away (obacity to 0) and new/updated rows should have a different background color for a time.

I tried the following:

1. Give each  the unique id attribute
2. set hx-ext="morph" and hx-swap="morph:outerHTML swap:1s"
3. Try to add some css as suggested in the documentation

However this does not work as intended because the htmx-swapping class is applied
to the outer most element only and not on the elements with a new id only.

What would be the usual approach here without marking new table rows in the response directly?

Comment: Nope, I haven't.

Comment: Maybe with using the `htmx-added` class instead of the `htmx-swapping` one, one can build something.

Comment: In this demo https://github.com/michalsn/codeigniter-htmx-demo there is the "paragraph" demo (here the views https://github.com/michalsn/codeigniter-htmx-demo/tree/main/src/Views/paragraphs) which makes use of sortable.js and idiomorph https://github.com/bigskysoftware/idiomorph maybe it can be of inspiration. If you scroll the idiomorph page you can read "Idiomorph was created to integrate with htmx and can be used as a swapping mechanism by including the Idiomorph-ext file in your HTML"